# no converter found capable of converting from AbstractJPAQuery to DTO

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Can anyone please tell how to use below native query in JPA? Now I am getting error message as converter not found.

**Sql query giving proper response in DB(MYSQL)**

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'PENDING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `pendingRequest`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'ACTIVE' or Status ='READY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `approvedRequest`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'FAILED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `rejectedRequest`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'ACTIVE' or Status ='READY' or Status ='PENDING' or Status ='FAILED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as totalRequest FROM fiu_consent_db.consent_request;
```

**Query which I have used in JPA Repository**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'PENDING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `pendingRequest`,\n" +
        "       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'ACTIVE' or Status ='READY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `approvedRequest`,\n" +
        "       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'FAILED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `rejectedRequest`,\n" +
        "       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'ACTIVE' or Status ='READY' or Status ='PENDING' or Status ='FAILED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `totalRequest` FROM fiu_consent_db.consent_request",nativeQuery = true)
ConsentRequestCount getAllConsentRequestCount();
```

**DTO that I created**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ConsentRequestCount {

    private long pendingRequest;
    private long approvedRequest;
    private long rejectedRequest;
    private long totalRequest;


}
```

I have created a separate DTO for these 4 fileds and taken data type as long(tried with int also) but its failing to map.

Can anyone please suggest me on this?

Comment: Hello, please add the query method also that is annotated with your `@Query`

Comment: Also add the full code not just parts e..g the DTO class, post it full not only its fields, for example have you created getters/setters to it?

Comment: @pleft added the method

Comment: And the error stacktrace please, try to give as much more info as you can in order for other members to be able to help you.

Comment: trying to add but getting some format issue and for getters and setters I have used lombok

Comment: Ok, please post `ConsentRequestCount` and I will try to edit and format your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-dto-native-queries/), class-based DTO projections do not work with native queries. You can switch over to interface-based DTO projections by changing your DTO class to interface

So this DTO:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ConsentRequestCount {

    private long pendingRequest;
    private long approvedRequest;
    private long rejectedRequest;
    private long totalRequest;

}
```

change it to an interface:

```
public interface ConsentRequestCount {

    long getPendingRequest();
    long getApprovedRequest();
    long getRejectedRequest();
    long getTotalRequest();
}
```